# Debugging break point not working?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

[image: Debug]

I can put break point in visual studio, when the application execution time. This error (see image link) will show it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's hard to understand wat are you asking, but if you mean that the debugger does not break on this point, please have a look at the message that appears when you hove the mouse over the breakpoint. You can also post it here if it's not clear.

Comment: try to put break point before running

Comment: already put break point before run time  but also not working..

Comment: Do you build in Release mode? If yes, change it to Debug

Comment: I my own experience, something like that happens mostly with the build solution which is out of date (in respect with the code), has no .pdb records or simply the compiler omitted the code from the build because the code is dead, meaning it will never be hit by any way.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see by the warning icon on the break point it shows that your source code is not aligned with the running code.

Try these

1. Do a Clean, then Rebuild and Run again
2. Where it says Debug, drop down and go to Configuration Manager and make sure all relevant projects are ticked for compiling.
3. If you are running ASP.NET, shutdown IIS Express, clean, rebuild and start IIS Express again.

Comment: I had to comment - You didn't mention that after shutdown, IIS needs to be started as well.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the addition. There are literally many more ways to clear out the potential caches of compiled code, I just listed some of the more common.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when your current build is different with your debugging code. Try rebuilding the Solution.

Do this by:

`Menu>Build>Rebuild`